# Android App Development: SELinux blocks permission to read file

Tags: java, android, selinux

I'm currently trying to get OpenJDK 17 JRE to work in my Android App. I've used some of the code by PojavLauncher to get a better understanding of how to get Java 17 to run on Android.

Java itself is able to output the version by running "java -version", but when I try to read a file, say a simple Main.class where it just outputs a System.out.println, SELinux blocks a certain read action. Now my guess is that this is the read action which is supposed to read Main.class.

It could be that the answer is really obvious but I don't have any clue if the folder from where I'm trying to execute the Main.class from doesn't have sufficient permissions or something.

The jre-runtime currently lies in "/data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/jre-runtime", and it seems to execute just fine. "Main.class" lies in "/data/user/0/com.example.myapplication" just for testing purposes.

Here is my C code (sorry that it's messy):

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "jre.h"
#include "log.h"

#define FULL_VERSION "1.8.0-internal"
#define DOT_VERSION "1.8"

static const char** const_jargs = NULL;
static const char** const_appclasspath = NULL;
static const jboolean const_javaw = JNI_FALSE;
static const jboolean const_cpwildcard = JNI_TRUE;
static const jint const_ergo_class = 0; // DEFAULT_POLICY

static int pfd[2];
static pthread_t thr;
static const char* tag = "javaexec";

typedef jint JLI_Launch_func(int argc, char ** argv, /* main argc, argc */
        int jargc, const char** jargv,          /* java args */
        int appclassc, const char** appclassv,  /* app classpath */
        const char* fullversion,                /* full version defined */
        const char* dotversion,                 /* dot version defined */
        const char* pname,                      /* program name */
        const char* lname,                      /* launcher name */
        jboolean javaargs,                      /* JAVA_ARGS */
        jboolean cpwildcard,                    /* classpath wildcard*/
        jboolean javaw,                         /* windows-only javaw */
        jint ergo                               /* ergonomics class policy */
);
typedef void (*android_update_LD_LIBRARY_PATH_t)(char*);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_myapplication_util_JREUtils_setLdLibraryPath(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jstring ldLibraryPath) {
    // jclass exception_cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError");

    android_update_LD_LIBRARY_PATH_t android_update_LD_LIBRARY_PATH;

    void *libdl_handle = dlopen("libdl.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    void *updateLdLibPath = dlsym(libdl_handle, "android_update_LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
    if (updateLdLibPath == NULL) {
        updateLdLibPath = dlsym(libdl_handle, "__loader_android_update_LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
        if (updateLdLibPath == NULL) {
            char *dl_error_c = dlerror();
            LOGE("Error getting symbol android_update_LD_LIBRARY_PATH: %s", dl_error_c);
            // (*env)->ThrowNew(env, exception_cls, dl_error_c);
        }
    }

    android_update_LD_LIBRARY_PATH = (android_update_LD_LIBRARY_PATH_t) updateLdLibPath;
    const char* ldLibPathUtf = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, ldLibraryPath, 0);
    android_update_LD_LIBRARY_PATH(ldLibPathUtf);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, ldLibraryPath, ldLibPathUtf);
}

int (*JVM_handle_linux_signal)(int signo, siginfo_t* siginfo, void* ucontext, int abort_if_unrecognized);

void free_char_array(JNIEnv *env, jobjectArray jstringArray, const char **charArray) {
    int num_rows = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jstringArray);
    jstring row;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
        row = (jstring) (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, jstringArray, i);
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, row, charArray[i]);
    }
}

int start_logger()
{

    /* make stdout line-buffered and stderr unbuffered */
    setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IOLBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, 0, _IONBF, 0);

    /* create the pipe and redirect stdout and stderr */
    pipe(pfd);
    dup2(pfd[1], 1);
    dup2(pfd[1], 2);

    /* spawn the logging thread */
    if(pthread_create(&thr, 0, thread_func, 0) == -1)
        return -1;
    pthread_detach(thr);
    return 0;
}

static void *thread_func(void* t)
{
    ssize_t rdsz;
    char buf[128];
    while((rdsz = read(pfd[0], buf, sizeof buf - 1)) > 0) {
        if(buf[rdsz - 1] == '\n') --rdsz;
        buf[rdsz] = 0;  /* add null-terminator */
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, tag, buf);
    }
    return 0;
}

char** convert_to_char_array(JNIEnv *env, jobjectArray jstringArray) {
    int num_rows = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jstringArray);
    char **cArray = (char **) malloc(num_rows * sizeof(char*));
    jstring row;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
        row = (jstring) (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, jstringArray, i);
        cArray[i] = (char*)(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, row, 0);
    }

    return cArray;
}

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, tag, "OnLoad!");

    start_logger();
    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}

static jint launchJVM(int margc, char** margv) {
   void* libjli = dlopen("libjli.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);

   // Boardwalk: silence
   // LOGD("JLI lib = %x", (int)libjli);
   if (NULL == libjli) {
       LOGE("JLI lib = NULL: %s", dlerror());
       return -1;
   }
   LOGD("Found JLI lib");

   JLI_Launch_func *pJLI_Launch =
          (JLI_Launch_func *)dlsym(libjli, "JLI_Launch");
    // Boardwalk: silence
    // LOGD("JLI_Launch = 0x%x", *(int*)&pJLI_Launch);

   if (NULL == pJLI_Launch) {
       LOGE("JLI_Launch = NULL");
       return -1;
   }

   LOGD("Calling JLI_Launch");

   return pJLI_Launch(margc, margv,
                   0, NULL, // sizeof(const_jargs) / sizeof(char *), const_jargs,
                   0, NULL, // sizeof(const_appclasspath) / sizeof(char *), const_appclasspath,
                   FULL_VERSION,
                   DOT_VERSION,
                   *margv, // (const_progname != NULL) ? const_progname : *margv,
                   *margv, // (const_launcher != NULL) ? const_launcher : *margv,
                   (const_jargs != NULL) ? JNI_TRUE : JNI_FALSE,
                   const_cpwildcard, const_javaw, const_ergo_class);
/*
   return pJLI_Launch(argc, argv,
       0, NULL, 0, NULL, FULL_VERSION,
       DOT_VERSION, *margv, *margv, // "java", "openjdk",
       JNI_FALSE, JNI_TRUE, JNI_FALSE, 0);
*/
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_myapplication_util_JREUtils_loadJVM(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jobjectArray argsArray) {
    /*#ifdef TRY_SIG2JVM
    void* libjvm = dlopen("libjvm.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (NULL == libjvm) {
      LOGE("JVM lib = NULL: %s", dlerror());
      return -1;
    }
    JVM_handle_linux_signal = dlsym(libjvm, "JVM_handle_linux_signal");
    #endif

    jint res = 0;
    // int i;
    //Prepare the signal trapper
    struct sigaction catcher;
    memset(&catcher,0,sizeof(sigaction));
    catcher.sa_sigaction = android_sigaction;
    catcher.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO|SA_RESTART;
    // SA_RESETHAND;
    #define CATCHSIG(X) sigaction(X, &catcher, &old_sa[X])
    CATCHSIG(SIGILL);
    //CATCHSIG(SIGABRT);
    CATCHSIG(SIGBUS);
    CATCHSIG(SIGFPE);
    #ifdef TRY_SIG2JVM
    CATCHSIG(SIGSEGV);
    #endif
    CATCHSIG(SIGSTKFLT);
    CATCHSIG(SIGPIPE);
    CATCHSIG(SIGXFSZ);
    //Signal trapper ready*/

    // Save dalvik JNIEnv pointer for JVM launch thread
    //pojav_environ->dalvikJNIEnvPtr_ANDROID = env;
    jint res = 0;

    if (argsArray == NULL) {
        LOGE("Args array null, returning");
        //handle error
        return 0;
    }

    int argc = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, argsArray);
    char **argv = convert_to_char_array(env, argsArray);

    LOGD("Done processing args");

    res = launchJVM(argc, argv);

    LOGD("Going to free args");
    free_char_array(env, argsArray, argv);

    LOGD("Free done");

    return res;
}

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_myapplication_util_JREUtils_dlopen(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jstring name) {
    const char *nameUtf = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, name, 0);
    void* handle = dlopen(nameUtf, RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        LOGE("dlopen %s failed: %s", nameUtf, dlerror());
    } else {
        LOGD("dlopen %s success", nameUtf);
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, name, nameUtf);
    return handle != NULL;
}
```

Basically, the app loads the needed libraries for java with the JNI dlopen method in initJVM(). Then it'll call the JNI loadJVM method.

```
public static void initJVM() {

        String mainPath = "/data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/jre-runtime/lib/";

        dlopen(mainPath + "libjli.so");
        if(!dlopen("libjvm.so")){
            Log.w("DynamicLoader","Failed to load with no path, trying with full path");
            dlopen(mainPath + "server/libjvm.so");
        }
        dlopen(mainPath + "libverify.so");
        dlopen(mainPath + "libjava.so");
        dlopen(mainPath + "libnet.so");
        dlopen(mainPath + "libnio.so");
        dlopen(mainPath + "libawt.so");
        //setLdLibraryPath(mainPath);
    }
```

Lastly, here is the call to loadJVM from inside Java:
`JREUtils.loadJVM("java", "-Xmx512M", "-Xms512M", "/data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/cache/Main.class");`

When I try to execute it with the setup above, I get a "avc: denied" error.

The specific error:
`W/e.myapplication: type=1400 audit(0.0:10408): avc: denied { read } for name="cgroups" dev="proc" ino=4026531857 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c162,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.example.myapplication`

Comment: That clearly shows it is trying to read from /proc/cgroups. At a guess it is trying to see if it is running inside a cgroup (the base technology for containers). You will need to disable that bit of code from the JRE or otherwise disable it through some flag.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I'm currently looking into a project called PojavLauncher which is doing similar things, so I'll look into that.